# Style.Add not working for display none/inline in asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

On a button click, I'm attempting to apply styles to two buttons to essentially swap them out - set one to display:inline and the other to display:none, however, the Control.Style.Add("display","none") and the Control.Style.Add("display","inline") are not working.

However, if I set seemingly any other Style setting, it works.  Control.Style.Add("background","#ff0000") works, so does Style.Remove("whatever") and Style.Clear()

My function is a simple button inside of a user control:

```
Protected Sub SimpleButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.AnotherTextBox.Text = ""  ' WORKS!
    Me.SimpleButton.Style.Remove("display")
    Me.SimpleButton.Style.Add("display", "none")
    Me.SimpleButton.Style.Add("background", "#ff0000")  ' WORKS!
    Me.AnotherSimpleButton.Style.Remove("display")
    Me.AnotherSimpleButton.Style.Add("display", "inline")

End Sub
```

My page code:

```
            <asp:LinkButton CausesValidation="false" Style="padding: 0px 4px; color: GrayText; font-weight: bold;" ID="AnotherSimpleButton" runat="server" Text="Add" Enabled="false"></asp:LinkButton>
           <asp:LinkButton CausesValidation="false" Style="padding: 0px 4px; color: Blue; font-weight: bold;display:none" ID="SimpleButton" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="SimpleButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I've tried with and without the above Style.Remove("display"), as well as using Style.Clear() and rebuilding the whole style - still no dice.  Is there something special about the display style?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Handles statement on the first line i.e. it should say:

```
Protected Sub SimpleButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton.click
```

Could it be that AnotherTextBox.Text and  Me.SimpleButton.Style.Add are being set in the Page.Load and that is why they appear to work?

Comment: In the page file, I've set the OnClick attribute in the <asp:Linkbutton> control.  Also, on a button click, the background color is changing from the page_load value of white to red. (I initially had a handle on it but had to switch to OnClick for other reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem - and of course it was user error.  A function tied to a later page event was adding "display" styles to those buttons, which is why only the "display" css was not working - it was simply being overridden.  (This was a major clue that I overlooked...)